# Onlick Desktop VS Mobile

Tags: html, css

Wondering if someone can lend me a hand here:

```
<div class="caption red_box noshadow lfl stl" importance="high"
data-x="0"
data-y="225"
data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-start="2200" data-speed="400" data-eosing="easeInSine">
<a href="https://maps.tech5.co.za/">CHECK COVERAGE</a>
</div>
```

This button when clicked/tapped on mobile doesn't work, you can test the live button by visiting this site: http://tech5.co.za/ and checking the sliders, none of the button work when viewing on mobile but are fine when using laptop/PC

I've tried setting priorities and setting "ontap" instead of onclick.

Any ideas from anyone? Highly appreciated

Comment: its working fine in mobile and on desktop both

Comment: What phone are you using? This definitely doesn't work for me using android, no matter which browser I use